# How to join textbox from other form to a datagrid in other form

Tags: vb6

basically what im tryin is making a log in page that is connected to a database, so in the next form im tryin to show the person info that enter their id (same database) using a datagrid. so how do i make the datagrid show the only needed information.

this is what i wrote on the next form

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_Click()
Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from STUDENTINFO where Name = '" + txtuser.Text + "'"
Adodc1.Refresh
Adodc1.Caption = Adodc1.RecordSource
End Sub
```

this is the user login code

```
Private Sub loginbtn_Click()
Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from STUDENTINFO where Name = '" + txtuser.Text + "'"
Adodc1.Refresh
If (Adodc1.Recordset.EOF = False) Then
    If (txtpass.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("ID")) Then
    MsgBox "Login Succeeded!"
    Adodc1.Caption = Adodc1.RecordSource
    StudentInfo.Show
    Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Password!", vbCritical, "Login"
    txtuser.Text = ""
    txtpass.Text = ""
    txtuser.SetFocus
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!", vbCritical, "Login"
     txtuser.Text = ""
    txtpass.Text = ""
    txtuser.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

i want in the next form to show the only info is needed for the user to see in the datagrid

Comment: Your tag needs to be vb6 or vb.net; not both. They are quite different. vb.net should be using ADO.net.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code

Answer (score 0):

Classic example of SQL injection vulnerability.

To make this work, you should at least use on your "next form":

```
Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from STUDENTINFO where Name = '" + LoginForm.txtuser.Text + "'"
```

To reference the loginform you should not unload it but only hide it, so it stays in memory. And fix the SQL injection vulnerability! At least like this:

```
Replace(LoginForm.txtuser.Text, "'", "''")
```